# Golang TLS handshake timeout, affecting go get and go code

Tags: macos, go, ssl

Golang can no longer complete TLS handshakes on my mac (Catalina, but this issue was present on Mojave first).

I've first noticed that this was occurring with failures to `go get`:

```
unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/text": https fetch: Get "https://golang.org/x/text?go-get=1": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

But I've also confirmed that this is affect golang code as well. Here's a basic example I expect to work:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://google.com")
    fmt.Printf("%v, %v\n", resp, err)
}
```

If I save this file as `main.go` and run it, I get the same error that I see from `go get`:

```
<nil>, Get "https://google.com": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong - https sites work fine on my browser, and when I use the Python `requests` package (or curl) I can access TLS sites just fine. It appears that somehow this is a go-specific failure.

Here's the output of `go env` for completeness:

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/nickchadwick/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/nickchadwick/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/nickchadwick/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/l9/r8jjmhm13hvcpwppdt9sklm00000gn/T/go-build865222134=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Any hints on solving this would be greatly appreciated! Not being able to `go get` things is a huge bummer.

Comment: When you open the url in the browser and inspect the certificate is there anything suggesting that the certificate is invalid or provided by another party? Some Big Corps (TM) have their own CA and issue their own certificates for all websites

Comment: No, the cert is valid and there's nothing stopping exactly the same commands working on my other machine.

I've worked around this problem by re-installing catalina from scratch, completely blowing away my machine - I'll leave this question up in case other folks run into this problem in future.

Answer (score 1):

After narrowing it down to a macOS problem, [this](https://1password.community/discussion/99219/error-net-http-tls-handshake-timeout#Comment_532519) fixed it: clean up the old Keychain Access System Certificates.

Comment: what keychain did you delete?

Comment: @alramdein old entries, a bunch of expired, I don't know which one was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar. When I build the binary on Mac without the `CGO_ENABLED` flag it seems to work. Just adding `CGO_ENABLED` env var during the build causes this issue.