# go get: net/http: TLS handshke timeout

Tags: go

When I was trying to go get something. Specifically:

go get -u gorm.io/datatypes

It keeps showing the following  two lines:

```
go: downloading gorm.io/datatypes v1.0.2
go get: gorm.io/datatypes@v1.0.2: verifying module: gorm.io/datatypes@v1.0.2: Get "https://sum.golang.google.cn/lookup/gorm.io/datatypes@v1.0.2": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Here attached my go env:

```
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/derekzhangv/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/derekzhangv/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/derekzhangv/Develop/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/derekzhangv/Develop/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.cn,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.google.cn"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.17.2"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/Users/derekzhangv/Develop/sites/biasura/biasura-go/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/1w/fm0bjyts2kn95_9fdmr_y2800000gn/T/go-build82472966=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

My question is: If there is any replacement for the "https://sum.golang.google.cn", if yes, how?

BTW: I can open this url(https://sum.golang.google.cn/lookup/gorm.io/datatypes@v1.0.2) by the local browser.

OS: macos big sur
Go version: 1.17.x

Thanks.

Comment: I have to set GOSUMDB=off temporarily to get the modules successfully.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [`golang/go/issues/31755`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31755#issuecomment-527611727), you are setting a checksum database with:

```
go env -w GOSUMDB=sum.golang.google.cn
```

Hopefully, it has not been blocked.

Since you are using `sum.golang.google.cn`, it might mean some certificate on your keychain need to be removed, as [described here](https://1password.community/discussion/99219/error-net-http-tls-handshake-timeout#Comment_532519), and mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62989130/6309):

> I started to clean my keychain step by step and after I removed a bunch of strange wildcard certificates it started to work.
>
> [image: https://us.v-cdn.net/5020219/uploads/editor/9q/7a5m4hg7b1no.png]